# Chem.SE tag map

Tags: discussion, tags

Using [this great tool developed by Piotr Migdal on Stats.SE](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/tag-map-for-crossvalidated), I've created a tag map for this site. The node sizes represent tag frequency, and the sizes of the links relate to how often the two tags an re found together. Pretty nifty; gives a quick overview of the site. For example, I can see that we're rather active in [homework](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) and [everyday-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everyday-chemistry). Don't know if that's a good thing, but it's something to ponder about :)

Enjoy!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hah. But, this doesn't come near [Physics.SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V41Z6.jpg). No offense. Two things I gotta say. When we compare both map, your colors are *dashing & smashing* luminous which hides most of the text, while the other is **smooth**. Moreover, the circles, bands and texts *too* doesn't look like they differ relatively.

So, the bands and circles have to be made much *sweeter*. For now, it looks much like a nice colored *bucky-ball* model ;-)

*And now, I see why this mod has been busy all over the week*...

Comment: Yeah, Piotr is better at GePhi than I am. He only did the sites which were available in SEDE, I had to request an csv file from Aarthi. I don't know the exact coloring he applied; there were some GePhi extensions which I didn't use.

Comment: @ManishEarth: If you're taking an intro, then it's totally *awesome*. More than enough for a *beta* site..! Someone gets angry now :P